# How to automate 'B2B Manual Data mapping' process using ibm-watson-cognitive and ibm-bluemix

Tags: mapping, ibm-cloud, datamapper, ibm-watson, b2b

For Example There are 2 Company
**GooDYear** and **Toyata** both want to do data mapping, as they are doing business together and want to exchange information.
GooDYear has data format **X12** (for example) and Toyata has format **EDIFACT** (for example).

And For Example Goodyear has `fname` and Toyata has `f_name`
But as standard both belongs to class `first_name`,so Now this process is very manual,developer do it by one-one mapping and time consuming ,my question how we can solve and automate it.`ibm-watson-cognitive` and `ibm-bluemix` has some API but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is about. Could you please explain in detail: (1) what you have done so far (ideally showing some code); (2) what the result should have looked like; (3) what the result actually looked like. Please take some time to write it down very clearly. Aim for writing at least three paragraphs and one snippet of code.

Comment: I dont have any code, it is general question that on data mapping, as i told 
fname---belongs-->first_name
f_name---belongs-->first_name
same as
dob---belongs-->Date_of_birth
date_birth---belongs-->Date_of_birth

Means 
**(fname,f_name)---->to map-->first_name
(dob,date_birth)---->to map-->Date_of_birth**

so there could be 1000 or more field  to map , how to do automatinc mapping using ibm-watson-cognitive api